# Vacances hivernales et estivales

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, adjectifs, niveau-de-langue

L'autre jour, avec mes collègues, on a parlé des congés. Je ne me rappelle pas la phrase exacte mais j'ai dis :

> Les vacances hivernales et estivales sont...

Un collègue natif m'a corrigé en disant que c'est mieux de dire, respectivement, vacances d'hiver et vacances d'été, ou même, avec une simple juxtaposition, vacances hiver et vacances été.

Pourquoi ne peut-on pas utiliser les adjectifs ? Ne sont-ils pas courants ?

Comment: Sans connaître les motivations de ce collègue peut-être recommande-t-il, dans un cadre scolaire ou universitaire,  d'utiliser la terminologie officielle de l'éducation nationale française,  qui parle bien de *vacances d'été* et de *vacances d'hiver* ? Par contre,la juxtaposition *vacances hiver/été* me surprend, je ne pense pas l'avoir déjà entendue.

Comment: On ne va non plus jamais aux "sports hivernaux", mais bien aux "sports d'hiver". Où l'on peut cependant pratiquer divers sports hivernaux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pourquoi ne peut-on pas utiliser les adjectifs ? Ne sont-ils pas courants ?

On peut utiliser ces adjectifs, ton collègue ne t'a pas dit que c'était incorrect, il t'a simplement recommandé d'utiliser la forme la plus habituelle et c'est effectivement très rare.

On dit environ quinze fois plus souvent *vacances d'été* que *vacances estivales* et soixante-quinze fois plus *vacances d'hiver* que *vacances hivernales*, que je n'ai jamais entendu.

[image]

Note: Le graphique ci dessus affiche la proportion de vacances d'été/d'hiver par rapport à vacances estivales/hivernales, pas la fréquence d'apparition absolue des expressions.

D'autre part, la juxtaposition (*vacances été* ou *vacances hiver*) ne se fait jamais à l'oral.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Estival est bien associé aux vacances alors qu'hivernal est plutôt négatif, associé au froid et au mauvais temps moins compatible avec des vacances. Aussi, on n'a qu'une période de vacances d'été (essentiellement juillet-août) alors que les vacances d'hiver, il y en a deux en France, les vacances de Noël et les vacances de février.

Answer (score 1):

"Vacances hivernales et estivales" est correct en français, mais il est plus naturel de dire vacances d'hiver et [vacances] d'été. C'est simplement une question d'usage.

Un peu comme "mousse à raser" qui est plus courant que "mousse de rasage".

Answer (score 1):

La réponse est basée sur une considération de l'adjectif « hivernal ».

Il n'est pas exact de dire que « vacances hivernales » n'est pas correct, c'est à dire qu' on peut utiliser cette combinaison, mais ce n'est [pas un terme courant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vacances+hivernales%2Cvacances+d%27hiver&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvacances%20hivernales%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvacances%20d%27%20hiver%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvacances%20hivernales%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvacances%20d%27%20hiver%3B%2Cc0) et il est [plutôt littéraire](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vacances+hivernales%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTl9a6-_PuAhVM5eAKHVMeAYIQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1).

Il s'agit tout simplement d'usage : les utilisateurs du français ne disent jamais ça dans la conversation, ou extrêmement peu.
Il n'y a pas de doute que le terme « vacances hivernales  » est défini (vacances qui se passent en hiver, qui prennent place en hiver).
Ce terme n'acquiert pas de légitimité seulement pour deux raisons ; tout d'abord, il existe une habitude qui consiste à ne dire presque seulement  que « vacances d'hiver » et lorsqu'on entend « vacances hivernales » cela donne l'impression qu'il s'agit d'autre chose, bien que l'on devrait savoir. Une autre raison se trouve dans la nature du mot « hivernal » : ce n'est pas du tout un mot du vocabulaire de tous les jours et même dans la langue écrite « d'hiver » est beaucoup plus [fréquent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%27hiver%2Chivernal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%27%20hiver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chivernal%3B%2Cc0).
On voit encore dans cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travaux+hivernaux%2Ctravaux+d%27hiver&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctravaux%20hivernaux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctravaux%20d%27%20hiver%3B%2Cc0) que l'adjectif « hivernal » a commencé à se renforcer dans l'usage mais que de tous temps il a existé une très forte préférence pour « d'hiver ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hivernal)) A. − Qui est propre à l'hiver, qui se produit en hiver. Synon. hibernal, hiémal (littér.); anton. estival.Ciel hivernal; ouragans hivernaux. Le vaste figuier qui verdit respecté De la neige hivernale et du torride été (Leconte de Lisle, Poèmes ant.,1874, p. 27).L'élégante et ferme dentelle des grands arbres hivernaux se détache (Du Bos, Journal,1928, p. 36).Des températures hivernales insuffisamment basses entravent la croissance, empêchant la dormance des bourgeons de se manifester complètement (Boulay, Arboric. et prod. fruit.,1961, p. 73).

« Vacances été » et « vacances hiver » se disent [très peu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vacances+hiver%2Cvacances+%C3%A9t%C3%A9%2Cvacances+d%27%C3%A9t%C3%A9%2Cvacances+d%27hiver&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvacances%20hiver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvacances%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvacances%20d%27%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvacances%20d%27%20hiver%3B%2Cc0). On trouve surtout des exemples de formulation en abrégé (langue des notifications, des statistiques, des brochures touristiques, …).